# Kafka consumer Error : ERROR Unknown error when running consumer: (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer)

Tags: apache-kafka

In my case, I am having Kafka binary kafka_2.11-1.0.0 install both on server and client side, but after creating the topic my consumer is not working when I was using *--bootstrap-server* instead of *--zookeeper*.

And I changed as per warning coming. Would you please update why the consumer is not working with expected one but working for the old way of calling consumer.

[image]

Comment: -bootstrap-server ***:2181 ? Seems 2181 is the Zookeeper port instead of the broker listener port.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments as well:

2181 is a common zookeeper port number.

It seems you tried to update the command but not the url. Make sure to use the actual broker url and port rather than trying to talk with the new command to the zookeeper port and url.